# Why $.ajax() call back function are never called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have a web application which has many buttons that call a code-behind page to execute some functions in SQL, then returns a message to the user..

All buttons work as expected. Except for the one I am about to describe.
Note that I have copied the same javascript code from another button click event.

Here is what happens when I click the button:

a) `click` event is triggered.

b) any code before the `$.ajax()` function works fine

c) code behind function is called, and works as expected

d) return value from code behind is fine.

e) success/error functions in `$.ajax()` are not triggered.

Why?? What is it that I am doing wrong here?

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='button approve' req_id='123' user_id='ahmad' reason='something'>
    Approve
</div>
```

And the following javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button.approve', function () {
  var req_id = $(this).attr('req_id');
  var reason = $(this).attr('reason');
  var user_id = $(this).attr('reason');

  alert('Before ajax');  //this is triggered normally.

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getData.aspx/approve",
        data: "{req_id:'" + req_id + "', reason:'" + reason + "',user_id:'" + user_id + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        succss: function (data) {
            alert('success');    //this never gets called
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert('error');      //this never gets called
        }
    });
});
```

and the following ASPX code behind:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Shared Function approve(ByVal req_id As String, ByVal user_id As String, ByVal reason As String) As String
        Dim reply As String = "-received data is " & req_id & user_id & reason

        Return reply   'in debug mode, the value of reply as valid
    End Function
```

Comment: any reason you're building your json data string manually? That's highly dangerous. Why build json-in-javascript? Why not just build a plain-jane Javascript object and pass that in directly? As is, you're highly vulnerable to creating JS syntax errors

Comment: @MarcB could you please elaborate more on your suggestion? A link would also be fine. Advanced thanks

Comment: `data: {req_id:req_id, reason:reason:user_id:user_id}`. Let javascript and jquery take care of the details. if you embed text in a json string, you'll end up doing `reason:'Miles O'Brien'`, and boom, syntax error - the javascript equivalent of an sql injection attack.

Comment: I already replace any semicolon and double qutation marks with somwthing else in text before calling ajax. I will try your method..

Comment: @Ahmad Manually serializing things is pretty much guaranteed to turn into a mess. Let the language do the work for you, follow Marc B's advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have a speling error. you wrote `succss`, it should be `success`

Answer (score 1):

Typo : `succss` should be `success`.